# when entering a new row in child table, how do i populate the foreign key ticketId using sequelize nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to figure out how I can populate the foreign key in my child table(subTaskTickets) from the parent table (Tickets).

When i create a Ticket, then I create a subTaskTicket, the ticketID and ETR_ID remain null and dont populate with the id from Ticket table.

Not sure how I can do this as i am new with sequelize, nodejs and mysql.

Here are my 2 modals:

1. SubTaskTicket model (child)

```
    const Sequelize = require("sequelize-v5");
    const sequelize = require("../connection");
    
    //create a new Date object with the current date and time
    const date = new Date();
    
    //extract the year and month from the date
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    
    //combine the year and month into a single string to be concat with id to form ETR_ID
    const yearMonth = year.toString().concat("-", month.toString(), "-ST");
    
    const SubTaskTicket = sequelize.define("subTaskTicket", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
       primaryKey: true
      },
      ETR_ID: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      // primaryKey: true,
        // defaultValue: ""
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
          model: 'tickets',
          key: 'ETR_ID'
        }
      },
      subTaskId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        defaultValue: "",
        primaryKey: true
      },
      Title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      Description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      Status: {
        type: Sequelize.CHAR,
        allowNull: false
      },
      ETR: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: yearMonth
      },
    });
    
    module.exports = SubTaskTicket;
```

2. Ticket model (Parent)

```
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize-v5');
    const sequelize = require('../connection');
    
    
    //create a new Date object with the current date and time
    const date = new Date();
    
    //extract the year and month from the date
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = date.getMonth()+1;
    
    //combine the year and month into a single string to be concat with id to form ETR_ID
    const yearMonth = year.toString().concat('-', month.toString(),'-');
    
    const Tickets = sequelize.define('tickets', {
     id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      },
        ETR_CAT:{
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        ETR_ID: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
            unique: true,
            defaultValue: ""
        },
        Title: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
    
 

   },
    Description:{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false

    },
    ETR: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: yearMonth
    }
});

module.exports = Tickets;
```

Here is my app.js file containing express etc:

```
    const express = require("express");
    const cors = require("cors");
    const app = express();
    const sequelize = require("./connection");
    const Tickets = require("./models/ticket.model");
    const SubTaskTicket = require('./models/subTaskTicket.model');
    var corsOptions = {
      origin: "http://localhost:8081"
    };
    
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));
    
    // parse requests of content-type - application/json
    app.use(express.json());
    
    // parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    
    // simple route
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.json({ message: "Welcome to Tylers application." });
    });
    
    require("./routes/ticket.routes")(app);
    Tickets.hasMany(SubTaskTicket, {
      as: 'subtaskticket'
    });
    SubTaskTicket.belongsTo(Tickets);
    Tickets.hasMany(SubTaskTicket);
    
    //will create tables from our modals, but also define relations in our DB 
    // sync() command for dev, add { force: true } so i can remake tables from scratch right away
    sequelize.sync().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        // set port, listen for requests
      const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
      app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
      });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Next are my 2 controllers for each model:

1. subTaskTicket controller

```
    const Sequelize = require("sequelize-v5");
    const sequelize = require("../connection");
    const subTaskTicket = require("../models/subTaskTicket.model");
    
    //Sequelized create format
    exports.createTicket = (req, res, next) => {
        const Title = req.body.Title;
        const Description = req.body.Description;
        const Status = req.body.Status;
       // const ETR = req.body.ETR;
       
      
       subTaskTicket.create({
          Title: Title,
          Status: Status,
          Description: Description,
          //ETR: ETR
        })
            .then(result => {
                //console.log(result);
                console.log("Created Ticket");
                sequelize.query('update subtasktickets set subTaskId = concat(ETR,id)');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
      }
    
      //Sequelized findAll
      exports.findAllTickets = (req, res, next) => {
        subTaskTicket.findAll({include: ["subtaskticket"]})
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
      }
      // Sequelized Find a single Tutorial with a id
      exports.findOneTicket = (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
    
        subTaskTicket.findByPk(id)
        .then(data => {
            if (data) {
                res.send(data);
            } else {
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: 'Cannot find Child Ticket with id = ' + id
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Error retrieving child Ticket with id= ' + id
            });
        }); 
      };
    
    //Sequilized Update Ticket identified by the id in the req
    exports.updateTicket = (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
      
        subTaskTicket.update(req.body, {
          where: { id: id }
        })
          .then(num => {
            if (num == 1) {
              res.send({
                message: "Child Ticket was updated successfully."
              });
            } else {
              res.send({
                message: `Cannot update Child Ticket with id=${id}. Maybe Child Ticket was not found or req.body is empty!`
              });
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
              message: "Error updating Ticket with id=" + id
            });
          });
      };
    
    // Sequilized Delete a Ticket with the specified id in the request
    exports.deleteTicket = (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
      
        subTaskTicket.destroy({
          where: { id: id }
        })
          .then(num => {
            if (num == 1) {
              res.send({
                message: "Child Ticket was deleted successfully!"
              });
            } else {
              res.send({
                message: `Cannot delete Child Ticket with id= ${id}. Maybe Child Ticket was not found!`
              });
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
              message: "Could not delete Ticket with id=" + id
            });
          });
      };
```

2. ticket.controller

```
    const Sequelize = require("sequelize-v5");
    const sequelize = require("../connection");
    const Tickets = require("../models/ticket.model");
    const { Op } = require("sequelize-v5");
    
    //Sequelized create format
    exports.createTicket = (req, res, next) => {
        const ETR_CAT = req.body.ETR_CAT;
        const Title = req.body.Title;
        const Description = req.body.Description;
        const ticketId = req.body.ticketId
       
      
        Tickets.create({
          ETR_CAT: ETR_CAT,
          Title: Title,
          Description: Description,
          
        })
            .then(result => {
                //console.log(result);
                console.log("Created Ticket");
                sequelize.query('update tickets set  ETR_ID = concat(ETR,id)');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
      }
    
      //Sequelized findAll
      exports.findAllTickets = (req, res, next) => {
        Tickets.findAll({include: ["subtaskticket"]})
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
      }
      // Sequelized Find a single Tutorial with a id
      exports.findOneTicket = (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
    
        Tickets.findByPk(id, {include: ["subtaskticket"]})
        .then(data => {
            if (data) {
                res.send(data);
            } else {
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: 'Cannot find Ticket with id = ' + id
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: 'Error retrieving Ticket with id= ' + id
            });
        }); 
      };
    
    //Sequilized Update Ticket identified by the id in the req
    exports.updateTicket = (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
      
        Tickets.update(req.body, {
          where: { id: id }
        })
          .then(num => {
            if (num == 1) {
              res.send({
                message: "Ticket was updated successfully."
              });
            } else {
              res.send({
                message: `Cannot update Ticket with id=${id}. Maybe Ticket was not found or req.body is empty!`
              });
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
              message: "Error updating Ticket with id=" + id
            });
          });
      };
    
    // Sequilized Delete a Ticket with the specified id in the request
    exports.deleteTicket = (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
      
        Tickets.destroy({
          where: { id: id }
        })
          .then(num => {
            if (num == 1) {
              res.send({
                message: "Ticket was deleted successfully!"
              });
            } else {
              res.send({
                message: `Cannot delete Ticket with id= ${id}. Maybe Ticket was not found!`
              });
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
              message: "Could not delete Ticket with id=" + id
            });
          });
      };
```

and this is my routes:

```
    module.exports = app => {
        const tickets = require("../controllers/ticket.controller");
        const subTaskTicket = require("../controllers/subTaskTicket.controller")
        var router = require("express").Router();
      
        // Create a new Tutorial
        router.post("/addTicket", tickets.createTicket);
        router.post("/addSubTicket", subTaskTicket.createTicket);
      
        // Retrieve all Tickets
        router.get("/allTickets", tickets.findAllTickets);
      
        // Retrieve a single Ticket with id
        router.get("/ticket/:id", tickets.findOneTicket);
      
        // Update a Ticket with id
        router.put("/updateTicket/:id", tickets.updateTicket);
      
        // Delete a Ticket with id
        router.delete("/deleteTicket/:id", tickets.deleteTicket);
      
          // // Delete all Tickets
          // router.delete("/", tickets.deleteAll);
      
        app.use("/api/tickets", router);
      };
```

Any ideas on what i am missing or how I can create a row in the subTaskTicket table that would populate the foreign keys with the proper id?

when i integrate this with a frontend (angular) I want Ticket to be the main ticket (ex has id =1) and then i can create "sub tickets" that would be tasks under that main ticket. So they would populate the subtaskticket table and be tied into that parent Ticket with the id = 1.

Any help would be appreciated! as i am stuck and trying to figure this out while using sequelize

Below is the query that is generated when i run my nodemon command. This is using sequelize.sync() in app.js to make the tables when i first create it.

```
    Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tickets` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `ETR_CAT` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `ETR_ID` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' UNIQUE , `Title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `Description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `ETR` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2022-12-', `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `ETR_ID`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
    Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `tickets`
    Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subTaskTickets` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `ETR_ID` VARCHAR(255), `subTaskId` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' UNIQUE , `Title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `Description` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `Status` CHAR(255) NOT NULL, `ETR` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2022-12-ST', `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `ticketId` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `subTaskId`), FOREIGN KEY (`ETR_ID`) REFERENCES `tickets` (`ETR_ID`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
    Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `subTaskTickets`
```

Comment: What fields in `SubTaskTicket` model are foreign keys? I suppose it should only one column (and not the one that acts as a primary key). Sequelize does not support composite primary and foreign keys.

Comment: @Anatoly hey, so with what is seen above, when i run my backend application, the following query generates:   (I updated the query at the bottom of the original post as its to long here) the foreign key is ETR_ID, however ticketId gets auto generated aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to choose only one auto-generated column as a primary key in both models
2. You need to indicate a foreign key column in associations explicitly (and the same for both paired associations) since you use the non-default name for it:

```js
Tickets.hasMany(SubTaskTicket, {
     foreignKey: 'ETR_ID' 
    });
    SubTaskTicket.belongsTo(Tickets, {
     foreignKey: 'ETR_ID' 
    });
```